# MKOverlayView drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext: when is it called?

Tags: ios5, mkmapview, mkannotation

I'm checking the breadcrumb example:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Breadcrumb/Introduction/Intro.html

On the iphone simulator, if I simulate somewhere off  the initial US view from the MKMapView, drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext: doesn't get called when it should draw something.

Why is that? When is the method called? What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

This is because of limitation set to display routes in the region of quarter of world size in height and width around the current location.

Check this code out in CrumbPath.m

```c
// bite off up to 1/4 of the world to draw into.
    MKMapPoint origin = points[0];
    origin.x -= MKMapSizeWorld.width / 8.0;
    origin.y -= MKMapSizeWorld.height / 8.0;
    MKMapSize size = MKMapSizeWorld;
    size.width /= 4.0;
    size.height /= 4.0;
    boundingMapRect = (MKMapRect) { origin, size };
    MKMapRect worldRect = MKMapRectMake(0, 0, MKMapSizeWorld.width, MKMapSizeWorld.height);
    boundingMapRect = MKMapRectIntersection(boundingMapRect, worldRect);
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of xCode are you using?

These are the requirements for the app:

BUILD REQUIREMENTS:

iOS 5.0 SDK or later

RUNTIME REQUIREMENTS:

iOS 4.0 or later

Comment: X code 4.3.2. I don't know why it sometimes works, sometimes not.

Comment: On my own app which implements the same logic works fine for some reason.